# How to integrate Buttons and Links into a Text in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I wondered how to add Buttons and Links to a SwiftUI Text. Some Example: In a long Text, some special Words are Buttons, or Links, like  in a Wikipedia Article:

[image]

There are some of the Words blue marked as links, how can I reach that in SwiftUI?

Thanks, Boothosh

Comment: It's still not very easy to do this in SwiftUI... NSAttributedString works though

Comment: Okay... how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I know the pain! I have spend a lot of time on internet reading articles on how to do the same and came across the easiest solution.

Reference for the solution [here](https://medium.com/swlh/clickable-link-on-a-swift-label-or-textview-98bbb067451d)

**1. Add TextView(...) to your project**

```
/// Text view with click able links
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>
        
        init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
            self.text = text
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.text.wrappedValue = textView.text
        }
    }
}
```

**Full Usage:**

```
    struct DetailsView: View {
@State var text : String = "Yo.. try https://google.com"
@State private var textStyle = UIFont.TextStyle.body

var body: some View {
        TextView(text: $text, textStyle: $textStyle)
  }
}
```